# hay alguna forma de generar código HTML dinámicamente, sin que quite la legibilidad

Tags: javascript, html

lo que yo quiero es hacer mi pagina web mas dinámica y/o ahorrar lineas en el archivo original.
ejemplo:

```
    <section class="header-menuSuperior">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header-menuSuperior-area">
            <div class="header-menuSuperior-area-item">
                <a href="#">Inicio</a>
            </div>
            <div class="header-menuSuperior-area-item">
                <a href="#">Blog</a>
            </div>
            <div class="header-menuSuperior-area-item">
                <a href="#">comunidad</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

este es el código de el menú superior de mi web, utilizando **JS** logre que se redujese a solo la etiqueda de apertura y la etiqueta de cierre.

```
    <section class="header-menuSuperior">
    </section>
```

pero el problema es que me tomo muchas lineas en jS y estoy seguro de que no es una buena forma de hacerlo. *conparto el codigo JS:*

```
const newElement = (Elemento, clases, nClases, id) => {
$elemento = document.createElement(Elemento);
if(nClases!=0){
    for (num = 0; num < clases.length; num++) {
        $elemento.className += " " + clases[num];
    }
}
if(id!=null){
    $elemento.id = id;
}
return $elemento;
```

}

y llamo la función con

```
header_menuSuperior(){
    this.$header_menuSuperior = document.querySelector('.header-menuSuperior');
    this.$header_menuSuperior__container = newElement('div', ['container'], 1, null);
    this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area = newElement('div', ['header-menuSuperior-area'], 1, null);
    this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area1 = newElement('div', ['header-menuSuperior-area-item'], 1, null);
    this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area2 = newElement('div', ['header-menuSuperior-area-item'], 1, null);
    this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area3 = newElement('div', ['header-menuSuperior-area-item'], 1, null);
    this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area__a1 = document.createElement('a');
        this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area__a1.href = '#';
        this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area__a1.innerHTML = 'Inicio';
    this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area__a2 = document.createElement('a');
        this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area__a2.href = '#';
        this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area__a2.innerHTML = 'Blog';
    this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area__a3 = document.createElement('a');
        this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area__a3.href = '#';
        this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area__a3.innerHTML = 'Comunidad';
    this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area1.appendChild(this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area__a1);
    this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area2.appendChild(this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area__a2);
    this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area3.appendChild(this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area__a3);
    this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area.appendChild(this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area1);
    this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area.appendChild(this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area2);
    this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area.appendChild(this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area3);
    this.$header_menuSuperior__container.appendChild(this.$header_menuSuperior__header_menuSuperior_area);
    this.$header_menuSuperior.appendChild(this.$header_menuSuperior__container);
}
```

como ven, para hacer esto, mejor lo dejo en html. igual considere hacerlo con PHP pero me quedo aún peor que el código anterior. asi que decidí ver si alguien conoce alguna libreria para hacer esto o algún Framework.

hay que recalcar que soy nuevo en desarrollo web.
agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: 1- aprende html5, css3 y eventos en javascript
2-aprende jquery y luego react o vue

Comment: React.js era justo lo que está buscando. Gracias.

Comment: cabe destacar que sin saber mucho llegaste a una solución que constituye metaprogramación. Eso no a cualquiera se le ocurre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no deseas usar librerías o frameworks, continúa leyendo:

Creo que vas bien encaminado, solo considera que mientras más completa esté la función para crear elementos, más podrás simplificar el resto del código. Incluso, crea otras funciones para evitar tareas repetitivas, por ejemplo, los `div` con enlace y características similares.

También, considera tener arreglos para elementos repetitivos, como los enlaces. Es más fácil recorrer un arreglo que ir creando cada uno. Además, con solo tocar el arreglo será suficiente para agregar o quitar enlaces, sin tener que modificar otras áreas del código.

```js
// Crear función asignando valor por defecto a parámetros opcionales
const newElement = (Elemento, clases = [], id = '', content = '', attribs = {}) => {
    let elemento = document.createElement(Elemento);
    // Agregar clases
    clases.forEach(clase => elemento.classList.add(clase));
    // Asignar ID si se proporcionó
    if(id) {
        elemento.id = id;
    }
    // ¿Hay contenido?
    if(content) {
        if(content instanceof Element || content instanceof HTMLDocument) {
            // Si es un elemento HTML, agregar con appendChild()
            elemento.appendChild(content);
        } else {
            // Agregar como HTML
            elemento.innerHTML = content;
        }
    }
    // Hay atributos?
    Object.keys(attribs).forEach(attr => {
        elemento.setAttribute(attr, attribs[attr]);
    });
    return elemento;
};

// Crea otra función para elementos del menú <div><a href></a></div>
const newMenuItem = (clase, href, text, parent) => {
    // Crear contenedor y agregar enlace como contenido
    let menuItem = newElement(
        'div', // Etiqueta
        [clase], // Lista de clases
        '', // Sin ID
        newElement('a', [], '', text, {href: href}) // Contenido
    );
    // Si se proporcionó padre, agregar contenedor
    if(parent) {
        parent.appendChild(menuItem);
    }
    return menuItem;
};
// Crear arreglo de enlaces con subarreglos [enlace, texto]
const linksMenuSuperior = [
    ['#', 'Inicio'],
    ['#', 'Blog'],
    ['#', 'Comunidad'],
];

// Crear menú superior
function headerMenuSuperior() {
    let menuSuperior = document.querySelector('.header-menuSuperior');
    // Crear contenedor y área
    let menuContainer = newElement('div', ['container']);
    let menuArea = newElement('div', ['header-menuSuperior-area']);
    // Crear enlaces y agregar a área
    linksMenuSuperior.forEach(link => {
        newMenuItem('header-menuSuperior-area-item', link[0], link[1], menuArea);
    });
    // Agregar área a contenedor y contenedor a menú
    menuContainer.appendChild(menuArea);
    menuSuperior.appendChild(menuContainer);
}

headerMenuSuperior();
```

```html
<section class="header-menuSuperior">
</section>
```

### Importante:

Esta propuesta está pensada para un aprendizaje básico y no intento minimizar o demeritar las capacidades, funcionalidades y características que se pueden obtener de librerías, frameworks y otros códigos de terceros.

Comment: gracias, me ayudo mucho tu código, y es verdaderamente increible como colocaste los comentaros. y el código de forma tan ordenada.
nunca había visto un código así de ordenado.